# UITableview reloading data after deleting row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a UITableview with "lessons" data fetch from a backend. The user can accept or refuse lessons with 2 uibuttons on the cell.

The problem is if the user refuse multiple lessons, the button seems to not be updated and refuse the wrong lesson.

Here is how I add my uibutton:

```
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"userWaitingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        UIButton *acceptBtn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
        acceptBtn.tag = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue] + 10000;
        [acceptBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(acceptLesson:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        UIButton *refuseBtn = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:201];
        refuseBtn.tag = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue] + 10000;
        [refuseBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(refuseLesson:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        NSLog(@"Btn TAG: %ld", (long)refuseBtn.tag);

        return cell;
```

I set the tag with the unique ID of the lesson from the backend database.

Here is how I handle the user tapping on a button:

```
- (void)refuseLesson:(id)sender
{
   UIButton *senderBtn = (UIButton *)sender;
   NSString *tmpUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld",
                      @"lesson/refuse/", senderBtn.tag - 10000];
   NSLog(@"tmpUrL : %@", tmpUrl);
   [dbService sendPostRequest:tmpUrl];
}
```

Here I can see in the NSLog that it's the wrong lesson ID.

When I finish the request I'm setting my data array like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [lessonList count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *lesson = [lessonList objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([[lesson objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue] == [[dataDic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue])
    {
        if ([[dataDic objectForKey:@"invitationStatus"] isEqualToString:@"accepted"])
        {
            [lesson setObject:@"accepted" forKey:@"invitationStatus"];
            [lesson setObject:[dataDic objectForKey:@"lesson_count"] forKey:@"lesson_count"];
            [lesson setObject:[dataDic objectForKey:@"lesson_done"] forKey:@"lesson_done"];
        }
        else if ([[dataDic objectForKey:@"invitationStatus"] isEqualToString:@"refused"])
        {
            [lesson setObject:@"refused" forKey:@"invitationStatus"];
            [lessonList removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        }
        [self.myTableView reloadData];
        NSLog(@"RELOADING");
        return ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked you are setting the tags right? NSLog the setting of each button tag and the address of the button object where you add the button to the cell. Then also print the address button object activated and its tag. Also make sure you are not adding the buttons more than once. Could be you have buttons off screen as cells are reused if you use dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier? You have to clear a cell every time before allocating its contents to be sure it is cleaned out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I did some test and I didn't precise correctly the bug, it happens after I refuse the first one (the first one disappear correctly), then the others one don't disappear or do anything and the tmpURL NSLog is always the same ID no matter what cell I click on. But the first one always work. Sometimes the second two, sometimes not.

Comment: When I print the button tag, in cellForRowAtIndexPath, after the first delete it's messed up. I create my cell like this: UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"userWaitingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; Do I need to clear something or?

Comment: You have to setup your cells fully each time. When you delete a cell, that cell will be reused for the next cell. So if you add buttons to a cell, you have to clear any existing buttons in case it's a reused cell.

Comment: Yeah but I don't really create a button cause I set up my cell in storyboard. I call my button by tag like I did in my first post, then why it doesn't give the right tag number? Also why it reuse the cell because I only want to remove it? Is it possible to use a storyboard cell without a reuseidentifier?

Comment: Thanks for extra info. Tags is your issue. Answer posted with proposed solution. For button actions etc, best to use storyboard CTRL drag and add the actions using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are fetching your buttons by a tag you set up in story board: 200 and 201.

In your code, you then change the tag of the buttons to new values:

```
`[[dic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue] + 10000`
```

At this point you have now changed the tags in the cell for those buttons.

On the next `[self myTableView reloadData];` call, cells will be reused rather than created. None of these cells will have a view with a valid tag of 200 or 201.

What the buttons will have is the original action you added first time round.

Quickest Solution:

1) CTLR drag in IB your button into the cell header and create an IBOutlet for each button: `acceptButton` and `cancelButton` say. This allows your code to be able to reference the buttons directly in code. Do not use the tags 200 and 201 as they are nolonger needed.

2) In your cell create code, remove the fetch by tag 200 and 201 and simply reference them directly. Something like:

```
 UIButton *acceptBtn = cell.acceptButton;
 acceptBtn.tag = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue] + 10000;

 UIButton *refuseBtn = cell.refuseButton;
 refuseBtn.tag = [[dic objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue] + 10000;

 NSLog(@"Btn TAG: %ld", (long)refuseBtn.tag);
 return cell;
```

3) CTRL - Drag your button prototype into your table view header and add an IBAction for each button. So use same code you have now for the actions.

This will stop the clash of the tags happening which I am pretty sure is your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was a tag issue!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting `tag`s I would recommend a more stable option:

This method finds a `UIView` with the class you declare and which is a superview of the view you supply:

```
- (id) findAncestorOfView: (UIView *) view WithClass: (Class) clss
{
    while (view && ![view isKindOfClass:clss])
        view = [view superview];
    return view;
}
```

And call the method as follows:

```
- (void)refuseLesson:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self findAncestorOfView:sender WithClass:[UITableViewCell class]];
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSDictionary * dic = [lessonList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *tmpUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                  @"lesson/refuse/", [dic objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"tmpUrL : %@", tmpUrl);
    [dbService sendPostRequest:tmpUrl];
}
```

What basically happens is that when `refuseLesson` and `acceptLesson` buttons are pressed, the Functions that you tied them are being called. And the specific button in the specific `UITableViewCell` is passed into this function as argument. From this `UIButton` we find the ancestor `UITableViewCell` and from there we get the `NSIndexPath` of the button user pressed. I believe this is more error-free than using tags by incrementing `+10000` as you did